# Finite Difference Approximation for the Laplacian in 2D that produces a nonsymmetric matrix

Tags: finite-difference, reference-request, poisson

Consider the following PDE

\begin{align}
-\Delta u  &= f \ \ \text{en} \ \ (0,1)\times (0,1) \label{P1}  \\
u &= 0  \ \ \text{en} \ \partial ((0,1)\times (0,1)) \label{P2}
\end{align}

if we use 5-point finite difference approximations we get a system
\begin{equation}
Ax = b  \label{Sist_Planteamiento}
\end{equation}

where the matrix $A$ is symmetric.

**Questions:**

1. Do you know a finite difference approximation that produces a system
   \begin{equation}
   Ax = b  
   \end{equation}
   where $A$ is nonsymmetric?
2. Do you know books or papers where I can study systems like the system in question 1?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Why do you want a nonsymmetric A? I'm genuinely curious!

Comment: I would say that you can just take a spatial scheme that is not centered, then your matrix maybe non-symmetric.

Comment: What @Laurent90 proposed is certainly a way to do it; another way would be to scale just one row of your linear system up or down.

Comment: I guess you could also use non-equally weighted (but still centered) finite difference approximations: $f'' \approx [w_1f(x+h) - w_2f(x) + w_3(x-h)]/h^2$ where $w_2 = w_1+w_3$ and $w_1\neq w_3$. As long as the discretization is consistent and stable, it would be convergent. But I don't know why anyone would want such a scheme aside from academic curiosity.

Comment: @ChennaK  I want to test a preconditioner in the system $A^{T}Ax=A^{T}b$.

Comment: @TheComander. I see. In that case, you will end up with a matrix whose condition number is square of that of the original matrix; the performance of the preconditioner will deteriorate.
If you want an unsymmetric matrix, then you can solve the advection or advection-diffusion equation.